# is there a way of file sharing in cordova app based on share it mechanism?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, wifi-direct, file-sharing

I am making an app for easy file sharing using cordova. I don't want to use bluetooth for file transfer. Is there any way like share it in hybrid app development as well which can use wi fi hotspot?

Comment: Please post her if you got any solution.